# external css override

Tags: html, css, apache-flex, button, accordion

i'm a newbie to flex. here is my problem

```
 .css

    s|Button,mx|Button
    {
    chrome-color: #CC0000;
     cornerRadius: 3;
     color: #CCCCCC;
     border-thickness:1;
     border-color:#000000;
    }

    mx|Accordion
    {
    chrome-color:#ffffff;
    }
```

the accordion's chrome color is being set to button's chrome color..also the dropdownlist's chrome color is being set to the same..
i tried..

```
<mx:accordion chromeColor="#ffffff" />
```

it is still #CC0000...
and when i remove s|Button...
i.e.,

```
mx|Button
{
chrome-color: #CC0000;
cornerRadius: 3;
color: #CCCCCC;
border-thickness:1;
border-color:#000000;
}
```

its normal...i don't want to change all the  to ...
Any HELP???

thanks in advance

Comment: It was probably a honest mistake, but if possible, please don't create duplicate accounts and questions. You can edit your question at any time to add more information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284440/external-css-override

Comment: @Pekka: seems the two questions were asked by different user(names)s.

Comment: @Kyle yup, but pretty certainly the same person

Comment: Absolutely, no doubt about that.

Comment: i'm really sorry. It won't happen again..

Answer (score 0):

There is no chrome-color style for Accordion component in *mx* namespace.
You can use chromeColor style when you apply Spark theme only. Spark theme adds chromeColor style to Accordion container. So it's a theme specific style.

Styles are either common or associated with a specific theme. If the style is common, it can be used with any theme. If a style is associated with a specific theme, it can only be used if your application uses that theme.